# Google Analytics shown events by category, but no events by action, how is that possible?

Tags: google-analytics

I checked events for a single day a week ago and saw there were three events in view "by category":

```
EVENT CATEGORY: Category_1
ACTION              |TOTAL EVENTS  |UNIQUE EVENTS
1. action_1          3              3
```

but there were no events inside view "by action":

```
EVENT CATEGORY: Category_1 >> EVENT ACTION: action_1
no events at all here
```

Why does it work this way?

Comment: Have you added Event tracking code to your site? Do you see actions in your real time view?

Comment: @NataliK. Yes, I can see them in real time. I added more details about my case here https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113013/google-analytics-not-all-events-are-shown-in-top-events because it looks like a new question.